# Spring batch my sql dump parsing issue

Tags: spring, spring-batch

**Problem statement**
I need to replace certain dates in my sql dump file and create another dump file. First I need to parse the create table definition and store information about date type columns. I may need to skip certain columns. After that I need to parser the "Insert into table" statements. Break this statement into rows and then into columns and then replace the dates.

**Solution** I am using Spring batch where reader is Composite Reader. I read the entire table definition (Drop statement, Create statement and Insert statements) in memory and then pass to processor to replace the dates. During reading I also split the insert statements into Rows and Column.

**Problem** This solution works fine for small dump but getting out of memory for large dumps. e.g. There is one table having long blobs and size is 2GB.

Any idea how can I fix the problem or Spring batch is not a right solution for this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: During parsing of row I split rows based on Opening bracket "("  and closing bracket ")". I split column based on comma (,). For that I need to replace these character in columns so that these character don't create any issues in split. I faced issues mainly because of long blob because size is too big to handle and keep all in memory.  Another solution I tried, don't store entire table in memory. When table definition comes store it in cache and use it for each insert statement parsing. Effectively read one line, process one line and write one line.

Comment: 1.  Please update your question with updates like you did in the comment so that we don't need to dig through comments to get the full picture.  2.  What happened when you read it line by line?  What was your commit interval?